# How is the order of compilation of source files decided?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, nmake

I have a workspace containing many *.c files, which I compile. (I could use any toolchain say MSVC6.0, or gcc etc)

Which source file is compiled first?

How is the order of the files to be compiled subsequently decided?

Answer (score 10):

The order of compilation is not specified by the C standard.

Since there is no need for the construction of global objects like in C++, there is no situation where the order of compilation is relevant in C.

Answer (score 5):

**VC**: By project folder, then alphabetically.
**GCC**: according to the make file order

Why is this important?, the completion order don't meter and doesn't effect the final build result.

Comment: It's important to understand why object code needs to linked afterwards.

Comment: It's important if some source file contains #import directive and others include header file that should be generated by this directive.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, this is not specified anywhere. Especially when using eg. parallel make, the order of compilation is pretty much arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

With `make`:

- The targets are addressed in the order they appear
- A dependency tree is built for each target and I would guess that the tree is traversed depth-first with post-order evaluation (seems to be the only way it will work, but I can't find anything that specifies this in the documentation)

As [jpalecek suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705866/how-is-the-order-of-compilation-of-source-files-decided/705938#705938), concurrent builds may be more complicated.

---

Some quotes from the GNU make docs:

> The double-colon rules for a target are executed in the order they appear in the makefile.

...

> If you specify several goals, make processes each of them in turn, in the order you name them.

Answer (score 1):

If it matters then you really need to set dependencies in your makefile to ensure some are built before others. Really you should first ask yourself why it matters.