# How does the make command avoid to recompile an unchanged source file?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, build, compilation

I am learning how to write a makefile, I want to know how it decides to recompile a object or not, there is little info about this, could you help me, thanks

```
test : main.o
    g++ main.o 
main.o : main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html

Comment: Your `Makefile` is probably wrong. Read more about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You probably want to explicit compilation and linking steps. An object file like `main.o` is not the same as an executable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Makefile know that a file changed and then recompile it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22630756/608639) Also see [How is the order of compilation of source files decided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/705866/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make` works by tracking dependencies.

In your case, you have `test` that depends on `main.o`, so if `main.o` has a modification date later than `test`, the command will be executed.

Same for `main.o` which will be regenerated in the dependency `main.cpp` was modified after `main.o` was modified.

Comment: yeah, I see. Previously I execute 'make' for many times and it will compile each time, and then I change `test` to `a.out`,it will not recompile until main.cpp was edit. Because, in the previous version, `make` cannot find a file named `test` and it will compile each time.

Comment: @Gordon You might also want to read about [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets).

Answer (score 0):

`make` looks at the `mtime`, that is, the modification time of the target and sources. If any of the sources are newer than the target, it makes the target. You can force make to remake the target with the `-B` option.