# Share sizeof(array) between two modules

Tags: c, arrays, compilation, linker

I want to share the value of `sizeof(array)` between two .c modules. The array is initialized in file A, so compiler knows the size at compile time and then I want to use the size of this array in another B file.

Example:
In A.c file:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
.
.
.

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++); // that works
```

In A.h file:

```
extern int arr[];
```

In B.c file:

```
#include "A.h"
.
.
.

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++); // here compiler doesn't know size of this arr
```

Is there a way to make this work? I know why this doesn't work but maybe there is a sneaky trick to workaround this.

Comment: In A.h: `extern int arr[3];`

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` doesn't yield the amount of elements. It yields the allocated bytes for `arr`, which should be 12 if `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Comment: do it the @pmg way if you have to. All methods in the answers are a very bad error prone, hard to maintain practices

Comment: @P__J__ But that doesn't satisfy the requirement of the question, to determine the size of the array in `A.c`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio it does in both files.

Comment: @P__J__ "*determine*" was maybe ambiguous. I meant "*specify*".

Comment: @pmg yeah but I don't want to use size just rely on 'auto' size by compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there a way to make this work? I know why this doesn't work but maybe there is a* sneaky *trick to workaround this.*

This is not very *sneaky*, but it works...

In `some.h`

```
//declare as extern for project global scope
extern int arr[];
extern size_t gSizeArray;
```

Then in `some.c`

```
//define and initialize extern variables in 1 (and only one) .c file, 
int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
size_t gSizeArray = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

In `someother.c` that includes `some.h`

```
#include "some.h"
//you can now see the value of gSizeArray in this file

printf("%zu\n%d,%d,%d\n", gSizeArray, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);//should output
```

> 3
> 1,2,3

*caveat*
The *value* of using an extern in this fashion  is that the value of that variable can change in one module, and that same value can be seen in any `.c` file that *includes* `some.h`

*corollary*
The *problem* of using an extern in this fashion is that the value of that variable can change in one module, and that same value can be seen in any `.c` file that *includes* `some.h`.

(or in other words, be careful.  Globals, in particular `extern` globals can be helpful, but they can also be dangerous. Particularly for maintainers of the code who are not also the author of the code, who may not be aware a variable is of `extern` scope, and use it unwittingly in inappropriate ways.

By the way, there is probably more than you'll ever want to know about using *extern* scope [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/645128).

Comment: It's safe if you make the `gSizeArray` `const`, but it's still a bit wasteful and not as flexible as an integer constant expression.

Comment: @PSkocik - I try to be explicit when naming anything that has global scope to encourage future maintainers to see where and how it is defined.  But I do favor flexibility over safety in this instance.

Comment: @PSkocik - Thank you!  I had just opened the editor, and you beat me to it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, some.c have to be compiled before someother.c?

Comment: That const  is game changer.

Comment: @dunajski - Yes, const does change things, and I prefer not using it in this case :).  And, the compiler will and linker will ensure the dependencies are all treated properly and in the right order.

Comment: @ryyker do you mean that, there is no need to compile some.c first? I tought that if I want to use gSizeArray in another modules with proper value that I have to compile it first to know array size.

Comment: @dunajski -  Yes, the compiler will do all the work, and the order source files are compiled does not matter.  The C standard does not specify order of compilation.   And although some compilers make provision to do so,  there is no advantage, or any reason AFAIK to order them.  The resulting binary is the product of _all_ source files submitted to the build stream equally, regardless of order.  BTW, ,Regarding the `const` keyword, its attributes are applied during the construction of the binary at compile time, unlike macros, or pre-compile defines.

Comment: @dunajski - (read more in this post about [compilation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705866/how-is-the-order-of-compilation-of-source-files-decided).)  So, because `gSizeArray` is declared in a location that will be visible to any file that includes it with a  `#include`  ( `extern size_t gSizeArray` ) , then it is defined once in only one `.c` file ( `size_t gSizeArray = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` ) array size will be known immediately at run-time to any other translation unit that included the header file that declared it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it f.e. by declaring both, the `size` object (which contains the amount of elements of `arr`) and the array `arr`, with the `extern` storage-class specifier so that they have external linkage in the header `A.h`. This header you include in both `.c` source files.

The value of the `size` object as well as the size of the array `arr` (by its initializer list) is specified in `A.c` but can be used in `B.c`.

---

The `A.h` file:

```
 #include <stdio.h>     // for size_t.

 extern int arr[];
 extern size_t size;
```

The `A.c` file:

```
 #include "A.h"
 #include <stdio.h>     // for size_t. 

 int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
 size_t size = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr[0]);

 for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
 {
      arr[i] = arr[i] - 1;
 }
```

The `B.c` file:

```
 #include "A.h"
 #include <stdio.h>

 for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
 {
      printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
 }
```

Output:

```
 0
 1 
 2
```

---

Side Note:

- `sizeof(arr)` does not yield the amount of elements in `arr`; It yields the amount of bytes allocated for the whole array `arr`. Since `arr` is an array of type `int` and not f.e. `char`, where the amounts of elements is equal to the amount of allocated byte, this result is different to the amount of elements.

  To gain the amount of elements use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the initializer a macro, share it through the header, and then you can use the compiler to recount the elements for the `extern` declaration:

```
//header.h
#define ARR_INIT { 1, 2, 3}
extern int arr[sizeof((int[])ARR_INIT)/sizeof(int)];

//file.c
#include "header.h"
int arr[] = ARR_INIT;
```

(
On gcc/clang/tinycc, you can also do:

```
//header.h
#define ARR_INIT (int[]){ 1, 2, 3}
extern int arr[sizeof(ARR_INIT)/sizeof(ARR_INIT[0])];

//file.c
#include "header.h"
int arr[] = ARR_INIT;
```

which is more typesafe but won't work with `-Wpedantic` as standard C doesn't allow compound literals as initializers for objects with static storage duration.
)

You could also share the size through a regular global, but that has  disadvantages as such a size would no longer be an integer constant expression and so it wouldn't be usable where those are required (array sizes, bitfield-widths, case labels, static initializers).

Answer (score 0):

no magic needed or another global variables.

in the .h file

```
extern int arr[3];
```

and then

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]));
}
```

Comment: The `[]` (as opposed to `[3]`) in the question kind of suggests the OP doesn't want to keep track of the count manually. If that's true, a little bit of magic *is* required to share the automatically computed count across translation units.

Comment: but it a bad practice. More generally it is how to design the static global pool memory - but the way of global [] array and another global variables is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `extern int arr[];` in the header file, you tell the compiler that:

- This variable is defined later. It isn't allocated here, but elsewhere.
- The size of this array is unknown (incomplete). I'll complete it later when I define the variable.

C works with something called *translation units*. A translation unit is a .c file and all the headers it includes. In your example `A.c` + `A.h` forms one translation unit, and `B.c + A.h` forms another. These are compiled independently.

In translation unit `A.c` + `A.h`, the compiler defines the variable and also gives it a size (3 int). Therefore the size of this array is known throughout that translation unit.

In translation unit `B.c` + `A.h`, you never define the variable. The compiler just knows that the array is defined "elsewhere", but it has no way to know the size.

---

The cause is `extern` spaghetti programming, where the same global variable is shared all over the place. The proper solution is to never do that. Use sound program design with private encapsulation instead. Let the array be allocated where it makes sense for it to be. Something along the lines of this (silly example):

array.h

```
int    get_array_item (size_t i);
void   set_array_item (size_t i, int val);
size_t get_array_size (void);
```

array.c

```
#include "array.h"

static int arr[] = {1,2,3};

int get_array_item (size_t i)
{
  assert(i < sizeof arr); // optional error handling
  return array[i];
}

void set_array_item (size_t i, int val)
{
  assert(i < sizeof arr); // optional error handling
  array[i] = val;
}

size_t get_array_size (void)
{
  return sizeof arr;
}
```

In a real application, this "array" would of course be something meaningful instead.