# Why does the MASM keyword SIZEOF MyByteArray always return 1 when using EXTERNDEF MyByteArray:BYTE

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Created an include file with this single externdef keyword

**num.inc**

```
EXTERNDEF MyByteArray:BYTE
```

Created an assembly file which defines a 10 byte array and includes num.inc

**num.asm**

```
option casemap:none

include num.inc

.data?
MyByteArray BYTE 10 DUP (?)

end
```

Created an assembly file which prints the size of the MyByteArray

**abs.asm**

```
option casemap:none

include num.inc

extrn printf:proc

.data
     szArray db 'MyByteArray = %d',0ah,0
     
.code

main proc
     mov     rax, SIZEOF MyByteArray
     mov     rdx,rax 
     mov     rcx,offset szArray
     sub     rsp,20h
     call    printf
     add     rsp,20h

     ret
main endp

end
```

The above files are assembled and linked with these commands below

**abs.bat**

```
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

ml64.exe abs.asm num.asm /link /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:libcmt.lib
```

Everything builds great, however, when running abs.exe, it output **MyByteArray = 1**

[image: therecanbeonlyone]

I was expecting the output to be **MyByteArray = 10**.
(Aside: If the array is defined locally without the externdef, the output is 10)

The workaround I've used is to simply replace the SIZEOF with the actual array size

```
mov     rax, 10
...
```

It's not ideal because if the array size changes, further modifications are required elsewhere to keep things in synch.

Is this behavior the result of the MASM assembler seeing the **SIZEOF MyByteArray** but only having access to **EXTERNDEF MyByteArray:BYTE**, so it returns a BYTE size of 1 instead of referencing the actual 10 byte array later on during linking?

Comment: You could export a separate symbol for the size using `SIZEOF` in the module where it is defined.

Comment: That's kind of annoying, maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Seems this related question in C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594612/share-sizeofarray-between-two-modules also has the same MASM quirk discussed here. Annoying, but not a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, define a size symbol where the array is defined

```
option casemap:none
include num.inc
.data?
MyByteArray BYTE 10 DUP (?)
.const
MyByteArraySize EQU SIZEOF MyByteArray
end
```

Then update the include file to

```
EXTERNDEF MyByteArray:BYTE
EXTERNDEF MyByteArraySize:ABS
```

Finally, in the main .asm file, reference the constant as

```
 mov     rax, MyByteArraySize
```

[image: 10bytes]

Thanks!